# Add minutes to current time, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, object

I would like to add 20 minutes to the current date. While browsing the messages already posted on this subject, I recovered a piece of code but I can not adapt it. Can you help me ?

```
// get the current date & time
var dateObj = Date.now();

// I do not understand what these values ​​are
dateObj += 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3;

// create a new Date object, using the adjusted time
dateObj = new Date(dateObj);
```

Comment: `date.setMinutes()`?

Comment: `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3` is three days in milliseconds.

Comment: "I do not understand what these values ​​are" 1000 (milliseconds in a second), 60 (seconds in a minute), 60 (minutes in an hour), 24 (hours in a day), 3 (days).

Comment: `new Date(Date.now()+20*60*1000);`

Comment: `date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 20)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a prototype function on Date Object if you want to use it in various places as it will reduce redundancy of code.

```
Date.prototype.add20minutes = function(){
 return this.setMinutes(this.getMinutes() + 20);
}
```

Now, you can simply call

```
var d = new Date();
d.add20minutes();
```

Comment: Be advised that in my testing, the foregoing returned a 32-bit integer that needed to be cast to a new Date object.

Answer (score 2):

Use this piece of code

```
var date = new Date();
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes()+20);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if setMinutes with values > 60 is defined or it works by accident. You can do it this way:

```
var current_ms = new Date().getTime();
var in20min = new Date(current_ms + (1000*60*20))
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript `Date` object has a method called `setMinutes`

```js
let d = new Date()

d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript when working with dates I like to use moment:

https://momentjs.com/

So you can do this:

moment().add(20, 'minutes');

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
var date = new Date();
var min = parseInt(date.getMinutes()+20);
date.setMinutes(min);
```